# How to create sitemap.xml with Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to figure out how to have a sitemap with sails.js

i tried using sitemap-express but it seems to be tailored to express routing.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is pretty old, yet I would like to put a solution here for seekers, like I landed here.

**First you need to install [sitemap-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap-generator)**

Say I have a **route** `'get /sitemap' : 'SitemapController.build_sitemap',`

**SitemapController.js**

```
    sitemap: function(req, res) {
       var fs = require('fs');
       
       var SitemapGenerator = require('sitemap-generator');
       var generator = new SitemapGenerator('https://your_website.com/');
       
       generator.on('done', function (sitemap) {
           console.log(sitemap);

           fs.writeFile("./assets/sitemap.xml", sitemap, function(err){
               if(err) {
                   return res.negotiate(err);
               }
               console.log("The file was saved!");
               return;  
           });
       });
       
       generator.start();
   },
```

> At this point a **sitemap.xml** file will be generated in ./assets directory *(you can put it wherever you want, its your choise/decision to make)*

**NOW** that you already have the .xml in your project, the only thing that is left is to return/render the sitemap.xml file to a route GET.

*Thanks*